# Replace a variable number of variable size

Tags: notepad++

I'm trying to append numbers to the beginning of an existing number. The piece I'm missing is that number can vary from 1-4 digits.

I have a script that contains "edit *123*", I want to replace that number with "edit *100123*". I tried a few things based on posts here, but I'm stuck how to give it a variable length number in the find and keep that whole number when appending 100 to the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<!\d)\d{1,4}(?!\d)`
- Replace with: `100$0`
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!\d) : negative lookbehind, make sure we don't have a digit before
\d{1,4} : 1 upto 4 digits
(?!\d)  : negative lookahead, make sure we don't have a digit after
```

**Replacement:**

```
100     : literally 100
$0      : the whole match
```